# How to say about any food availability in a hotel

Tags: phrase-request

Let's suppose I am working in a restaurant and someone asks me about the food, whether we have that food and I don't know about it. So how I can ask my manager about it? I mostly say:

> Do we do this food?

but most of the time it's confusing for me whether it's right or not.

Comment: Do we serve/cook this food?

Comment: Serve sounds like the best option to my ear

Comment: yea, 'Do we sever this food' sound perfect .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is this food still available in the menu?*
(Perhaps it's not and I want to make sure.)

*Do we do this food?* It's also a way to say it but awkward.
Stick with the suggestions that Khan gave you, *serve/cook*, they sound pretty natural, especially *Do we serve this food?*

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible questions here.

1. The food is on the menu, but you're wondering if it's currently in stock or if the restaurant has run out:

> Do we have anchovies?

or

> Do we have anchovies in stock?

2. The item sounds unfamiliar, you're not sure if it's an item the restaurant ***ever*** serves:

> Do we carry anchovies?